# PyQt window closes immediately (but not in debug mode)

Tags: python, pyqt

I am working on a project in PyQT5

My logic was:

> If pushButton (Login button) is pressed

> Navigate to WelcomeScreen

The issue is as soon as I press login button, I can see something open for extremely brief moment. Windows gets closed *but program is still running*

**But, Weirdly enough, when I debug the code, the Welcome Screen opens without any issue.**

Before asking this question, I made sure I searched for possible solutions. I've tried few such as returning `myWelcomewin` in `open_welcome_screen` method as specified here [PyQt window closes immediately after opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069713/pyqt-window-closes-immediately-after-opening)

P.S: I am working in PyCharm.

Code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from frontend import WelcomeScreen
from LoginForm import Ui_SVA
from WelcomeScreen import Ui_WelcomeScreen
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QDialog
import os
from os import path
import sqlite3

class WelcomeWindow(QDialog, Ui_WelcomeScreen):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WelcomeWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi('WelcomeScreen.ui', self)

class MainWindow(QDialog, Ui_SVA):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi('LoginForm.ui', self)

        # Connect button clicked signal to slot
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open_welcome_screen)

    def open_welcome_screen(self):
        # Hide the login screen
        self.hide()
        myWelcomewin = WelcomeWindow()
        myWelcomewin.show()
        myWelcomewin.raise_()
        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWin = MainWindow()
    myWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Change to `self.myWelcomewin = ...`

Comment: Solved it. Can you explain why it worked?

Comment: Read the linked posts for which yours was marked as duplicate.